# Evaluate xpath expression in xml body in python

Tags: python

I have an xpath with some php functions that needs to be evaluated against an xml body.
The expected result should be `true` or `false`.

Sample xpath:

```
condition 1 and
condition 2 and
boolean (
 
    [
        (
            not(php:functionString(
             
            )) and
            php:functionString(
               
            ) and
            php:functionString(
                

            ) >= 150000
        )
        or
        (
            not(php:functionString(
               some other conditions 
            )) and
            php:functionString(
                some conditions
            ) and
            php:functionString(
                some other conditions
            ) >= 150000
        )
    ]
)
"""
```

Is there a way I can evaluate this type of xpath against an xml body to get the `true` or `false` result?

Comment: That doesn't look like xpath to me - also, if your function bodies (which you redacted out) are PHP, why look for Python solution? Have you tried anything at all? Did you see some library or framework that made you think this should be doable in Python?

Comment: Yes, it's actually a PHP xpath. The reason I want to use python is because (1) I don't know php, (2) I'm working on a data analysis project that uses python. I've been looking all over the internet, but all of them is how to select xml using xpath...